# Unable to fetch host-name and path from CustomUrl?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, unit-test

i am unable to fetch host-name and path from Custom-Url.

```
String value='https://mcnabb--dev.com/_adssd/apex/apexPage';
List<String> abc = new List<String>();   
abc = value.split('/');
system.debug('add'+ abc.get(2));
```

but sometime **http** is not in url, that create problem,& like php **parse_url** is inbuilt function which give host-name and path.there is any inbuilt function in Apex.

Comment: Any updates. is my answer worked or not? any issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Use URL class's `getSalesforceBaseUrl()` method

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
```

This will return the url https://cs21.salesforce.com

For more info check URL class method **[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm)**